# MySQL is there a point to having a primary key on a lookup table which referrers to a primary key on another table which is indexed?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm just doing some basic normalisation but I don't have the answer for this, wondering if you guys can give me some info on right/wrong, do's/dont's etc.

So if I have:

[image]

I've always set a primary key (unique auto incrementer on lookup tables), in the image the lookup tables would be "page_downloads" and "page_includes" but I can guarantee those columns will never get used as they will only be queried via the page_id, same for so many definition tables.

So my question is: "Is there any point? What is the best practice thing to do? Always create the primary key even though it will never be used or don't bother creating it as it is fine to use the indexed int column which refers to a primary key in another table. Eg the relationship in the picture (page_id to page_id). Thoughts?"

Thanks

D

Comment: You must do as you've been doing as in the above image to link the related tables in relational database systems as it is the main point. You are certainly using primary key for everything to build your model. You should also set up foreign keys, so you wouldn't deal with deleting/updating dependent tables separately, i.e. deleting a page should end up with also deleting includes and downloads, or restrict deleting a page if it has any include or download records.

Comment: Just think about this: how can you say which download belongs to which page without the page_id pointing to the id in the page table? You'll see you are on the right track then.

Comment: Yes, I have foregin keys setup for cascade delete but again they are all using page_id, so again the look up tables (page_includes and page_downloads primary keys never get used)

Comment: what do you mean never get used? Their main usage is their existence already!

Comment: I am wondering is there any point in "page_download_id" primary key and "page_include_id" primary key, but it's just something I was told to do many years ago, so I've kept on doing it. But why if I never use that column and page_id is indexed on all tables?

Comment: SELECT * FROM PAGES INNER JOIN PAGE_INCLUDES ON page_id = page_id would be file look up, simple, primary key never used, cascade foreign key takes care of remove page, removes page includes and page_download entries, again all on page_id never using primary keys on the look up tables. So why bother creating the lookup table primary keys?

Comment: oh, I see. you are talking about the child table primary keys. they should be actually also named as "id" in their own tables but it is another story, page_download_id and page_include_id is fine. Yes, you don't need to keep them unless you edit those records individually. However, it is best practice to use "id" fields. It might be a nightmare when it comes to refactor your code and model for different needs in the future.

Comment: Lookup tables should never be used in that way, so as I thought, no need for the primary keys. Nice to have someone elses perspective.

Comment: I got ordered to create primary keys for id in lookup tables way back, but never got the justification as to why. I trusted the guru ;p

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111904/discussion-between-smozgur-and-darcey).

Comment: With an AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY on a common many-to-many table you will double the index size (RAM usage) and slow down your DML statements.

Comment: (@PaulSpiegel The impact on performance might be neglible)

Comment: @Strawberry, on my tests with 1M rows: 30-50% overhead on inserts/deletes and 150% overhead on index size. One might say: "It's nothing". But i think it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

No. While every table should have a PRIMARY KEY, it need not be a surrogate. In this instance, (page_id,file_id) is a valid compound PRIMARY KEY (as is (file_id,page_id)).

Answer (score 0):

To add some info to Strawberry's valid observations.

There's no absolute answer or best practice regarding the surrogate keys and usually this boils down to individual preference. There are both [advantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key#Advantages) and [disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key#Disadvantages) to using [surrogate keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key). Among the advantages, one could consider:

> Immutability Surrogate keys do not change while the row exists.
>   This has the following advantages:
>
> Applications cannot lose their reference to a row in the database
>   (since the identifier never changes). The primary or natural key data
>   can always be modified, even with databases that do not support
>   cascading updates across related foreign keys. Requirement
>   changes[edit] Attributes that uniquely identify an entity might
>   change, which might invalidate the suitability of natural keys.
>   Consider the following example:
>
> An employee's network user name is chosen as a natural key. Upon
>   merging with another company, new employees must be inserted. Some of
>   the new network user names create conflicts because their user names
>   were generated independently (when the companies were separate). In
>   these cases, generally a new attribute must be added to the natural
>   key (for example, an original_company column). With a surrogate key,
>   only the table that defines the surrogate key must be changed. With
>   natural keys, all tables (and possibly other, related software) that
>   use the natural key will have to change.
>
> Some problem domains do not clearly identify a suitable natural key.
>   Surrogate keys avoid choosing a natural key that might be incorrect.
>
> Performance[edit] Surrogate keys tend to be a compact data type, such
>   as a four-byte integer. This allows the database to query the single
>   key column faster than it could multiple columns. Furthermore a
>   non-redundant distribution of keys causes the resulting b-tree index
>   to be completely balanced. Surrogate keys are also less expensive to
>   join (fewer columns to compare) than compound keys.
>
> Compatibility While using several database application
>   development systems, drivers, and object-relational mapping systems,
>   such as Ruby on Rails or Hibernate, it is much easier to use an
>   integer or GUID surrogate keys for every table instead of natural keys
>   in order to support database-system-agnostic operations and
>   object-to-row mapping.
>
> Uniformity When every table has a uniform surrogate key, some
>   tasks can be easily automated by writing the code in a
>   table-independent way.
>
> Validation It is possible to design key-values that follow a
>   well-known pattern or structure which can be automatically verified.
>   For instance, the keys that are intended to be used in some column of
>   some table might be designed to "look differently from" those that are
>   intended to be used in another column or table, thereby simplifying
>   the detection of application errors in which the keys have been
>   misplaced. However, this characteristic of the surrogate keys should
>   never be used to drive any of the logic of the applications
>   themselves, as this would violate the principles of Database
>   normalization.

Comment: The first part does not relate to pure junction tables, because all columns are surrogate keys from other tables.